# Variadic templates and "expected a type" error

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm working (mainly for learning purposes) on own implementation of `tuple` and I've just encountered a problem. I have following code:

```
namespace Rose
{
    template<typename T>
    struct RemoveReference
    {
        typedef T Type;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct RemoveReference<T &>
    {
        typedef T Type;
    };

    template<typename... Elems>
    class Tuple;

    template<typename First, typename... Elems>
    class Tuple<First, Elems...>
    {
    public:
        Tuple(First a, Elems... more)
            : More(more...), Element(a)
        {
        }

        Tuple<First, Elems...> & operator=(const Tuple<RemoveReference<First>::Type,
                                           RemoveReference<Elems>::Type...> & rhs)
        {
            this->Element = rhs.Element;
            this->More = rhs.More;

            return *this;
        }

    private:
        Tuple<Elems...> More;
        First Element;
    };

    template<typename Only>
    class Tuple<Only>
    {
    public:
        Tuple(Only a) : Element(a)
        {
        }

        Tuple<Only> & operator=(const Tuple<RemoveReference<Only>::Type> & rhs)
        {
            this->Element = rhs.Element;

            return *this;
        }

    private:
        Only Element;
    };
}

int main()
{
    Rose::Tuple<int, float, int> t(1, 1.f, 2);
}
```

Which causes following error (there are more of them, but this one is essential):

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template struct Rose::Tuple'
>   error:   expected a type, got 'Rose::RemoveReference::Type'

I don't really understand what's this about. The `RemoveReference` trait works, when used alone.

Here are two testcases:

- [not working code I pasted above](http://ideone.com/fx2L8)
- [proof that `RemoveReference` works when used alone](http://ideone.com/Qav5c)

I have tried this code with G++ 4.6.1, 4.5.1 and Clang++ 2.9.

What's the reason for those errors to appear?

Comment: could you be missing a simple `typename`?

Comment: You mean in parameter `Tuple`s template parameter lists?

Comment: I don't know much about the rules of variadic temoplates, but are you sure you can do `RemoveReference<Elems>` when `Elems` is `typename... Elems`?

Comment: @SethCarnegie, that's why I've put `...` after the entire expression.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yay, worked. Could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Griwes just did. Not a very complete answer though...

Comment: `Tuple<Only> & operator=(const Tuple<typename RemoveReference<Only>::Type> & rhs)` for nested type?

Comment: @Griwes what does that do? Like I said, I don't know much about VTs.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, it unpacks parameters. For example: if you use the class as `A<int, int, float>` and class definition is `template<typename... Args> class A {...};`, then `Args...` used as template parameter list becomes `int, int, float`.

Comment: @Griwes I knew that, but why does it work after the expression `RemoveReference<>::Type`? It seems like you're trying to treat `int, int, float` as a single type to remove the `&` off from them. And `RemoveReference<>::Type` is only one type isn't it?

Comment: @SethCarnegie, no, in this particular case `RemoveReference<Elems>::Type...` (for `Elems` being `int, int, float` for example) it becomes `RemoveReference<int>::Type, RemoveReference<int>::Type, RemoveReference<float>::Type`.

Comment: @Griwes I guess that's a feature of C++ that turns a single expression with `...` in front of it and that is based on a "typename pack" into multiple expressions? That's cool and handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RemoveReference<T>::Type` is a dependent type, so you need to add `typename` here:

```
        Tuple<First, Elems...> & operator=(const Tuple<typename RemoveReference<First>::Type,
                                                       typename RemoveReference<Elems>::Type...> & rhs)
```

and probably other places.

Comment: Actually, it fixed all of the errors. See [here](http://ideone.com/qIiSg). Seems I really must try to put `typename` in every possible place before trying anything else. Also, I think you meant `RemoveReference<T>::Type`, not `tuple<T>::type` at the very beginning of your answer, didn't you?

Comment: @Griwes, yes, I meant RemoveReference. Thanks for the correction.